# Set option 9 in SQL Server stored procedure using WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 for TLS 1.2

Tags: sql-server, tls1.2

I am trying to connect to a web service that only supports TLS 1.2. I'm having trouble with the syntax for setting option9 (`WinHttpRequestOption_SecureProtocols`) to use TLS 1.2

I've tried

```
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @objectID, 'Option', '2720', 9
```

but no dice.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MSSQL - I've tried EXEC sp_OASetProperty @objectID, 'Option', '2720', 9   but no dice

Comment: Just to understand - are you in the insane situation where someone will allow you to freely make use of the `sp_OAXxx` stored procedures for COM interop whilst at the same time disllowing you from using the CLR integration? Because if not, ditch the COM code and start writing some .NET code.

Comment: yeah, that sounds strangely accurate to my situation...

Comment: *Don't* use those stored procedures. It's *not* the way to make HTTP requests from inside the server. This was abandoned in 2005, 13 years ago, when SQLCLR was introduced. For example, did you use try blocks to ensure the COM objects you create are disposed even if an error occurs?

Comment: First of all, HTTP requests should be performed *outside* the server. It's easier *and* scales a lot better to use client code, powershell, curl or any other script to make HTTP calls. If you *absolutely* have to, use SQLCLR and HttpWebRequest or WebClient but be aware that a) those calls are blocking and b) whether TLS1.2 is used depends on the OS *and* the CLR version used by SQL Server. Before .NET 4.6, you had to explicitly specify that you want to use TLS1.2. After 4.6, the OS's most secure option is used

Comment: What OS, SQL Server version are you using? 2008R2 for example needs configuration to enable the use of TLS1.2 by default

Comment: I agree it's old, outdated, and ugly, but in the case I'm in right now - it's literally the only option. However, besides the negatives you mentioned, they have worked well for this project. It's SQL 2012 sp4 running on Windows 2008 R2 server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not because it's a good idea, but so that no one else has to figure out how to use the horrid sp_OAxxx stored procedures...

Here's an update to my [ancient HTTP stored procedure](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/uDlUxG4K1l4/EdCoJdn_O_4J) to use both WinHttp and set that option.  The Option property is an "indexed property" so calling it with sp_OASetProperty is wierd.

```
create or alter procedure get_http @url varchar(2000) 
as
begin
/*
exec get_http 'https://www.bing.com'
*/
    declare @hr int;
    declare @win int;
    declare @errorMessage varchar(2000);

    begin try

      EXEC @hr=sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1',@win OUT 
      IF @hr <> 0
      begin;
        set @errorMessage = concat('sp_OACreate failed ', convert(varchar(20),cast(@hr as varbinary(4)),1));
        throw 60000, @errorMessage, 1;
      end;

      EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @win, 'Open',NULL,'GET',@url,'false'
      IF @hr <> 0
      begin;
        set @errorMessage = concat('Open failed ', convert(varchar(20),cast(@hr as varbinary(4)),1));
        throw 60000, @errorMessage, 1;
      end;

      --Option is an indexed property, so newvalue = 2048 and index = 9
      --sp_OASetProperty objecttoken , propertyname , newvalue [ , index... ] 
      EXEC @hr=sp_OASetProperty @win, 'Option', 2048, 9
      IF @hr <> 0
      begin;
        set @errorMessage = concat('set Option failed ', convert(varchar(20),cast(@hr as varbinary(4)),1) );
        throw 60000, @errorMessage, 1;
      end;

      EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @win,'Send'
      IF @hr <> 0
      begin;
        set @errorMessage = concat('Send failed ', convert(varchar(20),cast(@hr as varbinary(4)),1));
        throw 60000, @errorMessage, 1;
      end;

      declare @status int
      EXEC @hr=sp_OAGetProperty @win,'Status', @status out
      IF @hr <> 0
      begin;
        set @errorMessage = concat('get Status failed ', convert(varchar(20),cast(@hr as varbinary(4)),1));
        throw 60000, @errorMessage, 1;
      end;

      if @status <> 200
      begin;
        set @errorMessage = concat('web request failed ', @status);
        throw 60000, @errorMessage, 1;
      end;

      declare @response table(text nvarchar(max));

      insert into @response(text)
      EXEC @hr=sp_OAGetProperty @win,'ResponseText';
      IF @hr <> 0
      begin;
        set @errorMessage = concat('get ResponseText failed ', convert(varchar(20),cast(@hr as varbinary(4)),1));
        throw 60000, @errorMessage, 1;
      end;

      select *
      from @response

      EXEC @hr=sp_OADestroy @win 
      IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win;

    end try
    begin catch
      declare @error varchar(200) = error_message()
      declare @source varchar(200);
      declare @description varchar(200);
      declare @helpfile varchar(200);
      declare @helpid int;

      exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win, @source out, @description out, @helpfile out, @helpid out;
      declare @msg varchar(max) = concat('COM Failure ', @error,' ',@source,' ',@description)

      EXEC @hr=sp_OADestroy @win; 
      --IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win;
      throw 60000, @msg, 1;

    end catch
end
```