# Call to web service from Sql Server - SSL issue

Tags: sql-server, windows, web-services, ssl

I am using a stored proc to call a web service running on another machine from SQL Server using sp_OACreate/sp_OAMethod... Worked fine until I added SSL certificate to web server hosting web service. Now SQL Server can't make the call. Any ideas?

I have added the certificate to the local SQL Server machine's local store in Personal\Certificates folder.  Still can't make the call.

```
DECLARE @theLink as varchar(500)
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

PRINT 'Preparing to call web service - email'

SET @theLink = '[webservice link is here with https://...]'
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                                                              @theLink,
                                                              'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select @ResponseText

PRINT 'Finished call to web service'
PRINT 'RESPONSE: ' + @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
GO
```

Should call .net web service which sends email and logs back to database.  Not working :(

Comment: Posting the error is going to be really helpful here. We can't run your code, so unless you tell us exactly what's happening, the error you get, and the response you're expecting, no one here can help you/

Comment: Unfortunately I am not seeing an error in the query window and no error in Windows event logs - the web service just doesn't get called. I can run the web service from a browser with no issues - just not from within SQL Server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set option 9 in SQL Server stored procedure using WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 for TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086558/set-option-9-in-sql-server-stored-procedure-using-winhttp-winhttprequest-5-1-for)