# Querying web services JSON from SQL server

Tags: json, sql-server

I'm following [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/importing-json-web-services-applications-sql-server/) tutorial. I created GetWebService stored procedure from tutorial, and example from there works fine

```
  DECLARE @response NVARCHAR(MAX) 
  EXECUTE dbo.GetWebService 'http://headers.jsontest.com/', @response OUTPUT
  SELECT  @response
```

But, when I try to run this:

```
DECLARE @response NVARCHAR(MAX) 
  EXECUTE dbo.GetWebService 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo', @response OUTPUT
  SELECT  @response
```

it fails

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.GetWebService, Line 48 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   sp_OAMethod read response failed

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't follow that tutorial.  You should use a CLR stored procedure to make web service calls from SQL Server.  There are lots of samples out there.

If you *are* going to use the deprecated and potentially dangerous sp_OAxxx stored procedures, still don't follow that tutorial.  It's got issues.  Try the implementation in my answer here instead: [Set option 9 in SQL Server stored procedure using WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 for TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086558/set-option-9-in-sql-server-stored-procedure-using-winhttp-winhttprequest-5-1-for/53088460#53088460)

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly good. Also, I guess that using SQL sever in such situations is not that efficient. Could you please share some good sources to study how to do better if I want to store that sort of example in SQL Server tables, maybe C# or Java would be more efficient.

Comment: This method is as efficient as any.  More, probably, since it uses a un-managed built-in Windows component.  The issue is complexity, memory-safety, etc. C# or PowerShell, or even Python, etc running outside of SQL Server would be the preferred method.