# SQL Server sp_OAMethod Returns NULL When Calling WebAPI

Tags: json, sql-server, rest, restful-url

We are trying to retrieve some JSON results provided by a private third party WebAPI. For some reason, one of the calls is returning NULL every time. If we use different URI call to access different info it works. But, this one in particular will not work.

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
Declare @URI varchar(max) = 'https://thethridpartysite.com/api/1234/listorders/'

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', @URI, 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

SELECT @ResponseText;
```

In the above, if I change the "listorders" to "listproducts" it will work.

I thought it might be because the "listorders" is returning more than 8000 characters, but when I changed the @ResponseText variable "varchar(max)", I still got NULL

Comment: Are you sure the fault lies with you? Might there not be an issue with the third party?

Comment: Partial list of things you're doing wrong: 1) You're using HTTP from TSQL.  2) You're using sp_OAxxx instead of SQL CLR. 3) You're using the wrong HTTP component.  4) You're not checking the success of each call, and conditionally fetching error infomation.

Comment: I don't believe the fault lies with the 3rd party (could be, but unsure). Reason is I can get it returned to me in Excel VBA

Comment: David. All things I'd love to learn about. Any references you point to I can read? In the meantime, for #1, #2, and 3#... why would it work for other calls?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086558/set-option-9-in-sql-server-stored-procedure-using-winhttp-winhttprequest-5-1-for/53088460#53088460

Comment: I will try it and report back. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the error "COM Failure web request failed 404" at the "if @status <> 200" error check. Any ideas? Aslo note I checked from VBA and the json returned is 63k characters long. And, when I place it in an online parser it says it is not formatted correctly. However the errors are related to carriage returns in seemingly weird spots (e.g. when you have "mykey:myvalue", it is returned with a carriage return between the first quote and 'mykey'.. i wouldn't think that would break anything).

Answer (score 2):

After trying a number of things, I was not able to figure out why the OLE Automation method was returning a NULL value. So I eventually built everything using SQL CLR and it worked.

I effectively used the steps discussed at the following link (with my own twist on things):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqllive/2008/06/18/accessing-rest-based-web-services-using-sql-clr/

There were some learning pains and a number issues I ran into, but I was able to figure them out. Good luck to those who follow and thank you those who responded to my OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(800);
Use below code for calling API

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 '@url', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT


Select @ResponseText
Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**