# Send requests to rest API from SQL Server and check http code returned

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, cron

I'm attempting to send json data to a rest API, ideally from SQL Server 2016.  I have come across the following code (from https://gist.github.com/theorigin/fa3c58406ff7b4565ca2) that uses sp_OAMethod and have tested it using webhook.site so I know it sends, but I can't see the http response code from SQL which is what I need to view... the API in question sends a 400 response along with an error message if there is an issue with a submission, or a 200 if everything was correct.

The SQL code returns a NULL column under all scenarios. At present I have a PHP application that I have written that does all this for me, except it is not automated. The application runs through csv files and sends json one line at a time to the endpoint. Before I alter it to look at query results rather than csv files, and before I start looking at adding this to a cron job (or perhaps a scheduled task in Windows?), I have been wondering if what I am trying to achieve is possible using SQL Server, which is where all my data is stored. This may be a round peg into a square hole though and if so then I will discount this method.

```
DECLARE @Object AS INT;
DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @Body AS VARCHAR(8000) = 
'{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
}'  

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'post','https://webhook.site/1234', 'false'

EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @body

EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
SELECT @ResponseText

EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Ideally I will see '200' or '400' as a response for each request and I can parse these after the stored procedure has run.

Any help or suggestions are very welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set option 9 in SQL Server stored procedure using WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 for TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086558/set-option-9-in-sql-server-stored-procedure-using-winhttp-winhttprequest-5-1-for)

Comment: So in other words the sp_OA procedures are a bad idea and I should look at alternatives.  SQL CLR?

Comment: Basically, yes. There's a relevant sample here: https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/features/sql-clr/Curl

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that the reason is because you do `SELECT @ResponseText` and then you do nothing with whatever the `SELECT` is returning and finally you destroy the object.

Try to assign the response you hold in @ResponseText to another variable. In the below example I'm doing a login to a rest API and then I assign the response to another variable:

```
EXEC sp_OACREATE 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'Open', NULL, 'POST', 'https://url.net/api/LoginUser', 'false'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'

DECLARE @len int
SET @len = len(@body)

EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key','4f82f9d067914287979884f920d86ffb'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Ocp-Apim-Trace:true'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Length', @len
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SETRequestBody', null, 'Body', @body
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'Send', null, @body
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'ResponseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

SELECT @Token=@ResponseText

EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object

SET @Token='Bearer '+ REPLACE(@Token, '"', '')

PRINT @Token
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying using SELECT into a temp table to evaluate results.

```sql
DECLARE @tableResponseText TABLE (
    [ResponseText] VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
```

Your setup/send statements

Collect the response data

```sql
EXEC @RC = sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'status', @HttpResponseCode OUT
INSERT INTO @tableResponseText ([ResponseText]) EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'
```