# SQL HTTP Function or Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I am making a call to my web api from within sql.
The following code works as intended and returns a single large JSON response into the table.

My problem is turning this into a function or procedure that is useful.

I am unable to use 'INSERT EXEC' within a function, and I am required to do so, because the response is too large for the scalar limit on sp_OAGetProperty.

I am unable to obtain the response as a select out of the stored proc version because that creates a nested EXEC error.

I am at a loss on how to turn this into something I can call elsewhere and actually work with the data returned

```
DECLARE @contentType NVARCHAR(64);
DECLARE @postData NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @responseTable table(content nvarchar(max));
DECLARE @ret INT;
DECLARE @token INT;
DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @Authorization NVARCHAR(200);


DECLARE @AccessToken varchar(500) = 'REDACTED'
DECLARE @ApiMethod varchar(200) = 'GET'

SET @contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
SET @postData = 'TestParam=123';
SET @url = 'http://localhost/api/testmethod';

IF @ApiMethod = 'GET'
BEGIN
    SET @url = @url + '?' + @postData;
END

EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, @ApiMethod, @url, 'false';
DECLARE @bearer varchar(600) = 'Bearer ' + @AccessToken;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'SetRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', @bearer
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;

IF @ApiMethod = 'POST'
BEGIN
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', NULL, @postData;
END

IF @ApiMethod = 'GET'
BEGIN
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', NULL, NULL;
END

INSERT INTO @responseTable exec sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText'

EXEC @ret = sp_OADestroy @token;

SELECT * FROM @responseTable
```

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is to convert this to a CLR function or stored procedure, if the CLR is available to you.

Comment: Yeah, trying the CLR now, but I'm not very familiar with how CLR works and it's becoming a struggle

Comment: It's about what you've got to work with...  SQL Server isn't really built for this type of activity.

Comment: Any idea how to allow the CLR access to the system.net.http.dll? I keep getting
CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'System.Net.Http' failed because assembly 'System.Net.Http' failed verification even though I try to load with PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs this, I ended up using a stored proc with an output parameter to return the json response from the API and then parsed it outside the proc. I'm still looking for a better solution for putting part 2 inside a proc/function, but this works for now

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[CallApiProc]
(
    @AccessToken varchar(500),
    @ApiPath varchar(200),
    @ApiMethod varchar(200),
    @FormEncodedBody varchar(max),
    @response varchar(max) OUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @authHeader NVARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE @contentType NVARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE @postData NVARCHAR(2000);
    declare @responseTable table(content nvarchar(max));
    DECLARE @responseText NVARCHAR(max);
    DECLARE @responseXML NVARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE @ret INT;
    DECLARE @status NVARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE @statusText NVARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE @token INT;
    DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(256);
    DECLARE @Authorization NVARCHAR(200);

    --set your post params
    SET @contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    SET @postData = @FormEncodedBody;
    SET @url = 'http://localhost/api/' + @ApiPath;

    IF @ApiMethod = 'GET'
    BEGIN
        SET @url = @url + '?' + @FormEncodedBody
    END

    -- Open the connection.
    EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
    IF @ret <> 0 
    BEGIN
        declare @errorOpen int = cast('Unable to open API connection' as int);
    END
    -- Send the request.
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, @ApiMethod, @url, 'false';
    --set a custom header Authorization is the header key and VALUE is the value in the header
    declare @bearer varchar(600) = 'Bearer ' + @AccessToken;
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'SetRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', @bearer

    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;

    IF @ApiMethod = 'POST'
    BEGIN
        EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', NULL, @postData;
    END

    IF @ApiMethod = 'GET'
    BEGIN
        EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', NULL, NULL;
    END

    -- Handle the response.
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @status OUT;
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;

    insert into @responseTable exec sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText'


    -- Close the connection.
    EXEC @ret = sp_OADestroy @token;
    IF @ret <> 0 
    BEGIN
        declare @errorClose int = cast('Failed to close API connection' as int);
    END

    select @response = content FROM @responseTable;

END
```

and then I called it like this

```
declare @AccessToken varchar(500) = 'REDACTED'

declare @StartDate DATETIME = '2019-12-01';
declare @EndDate DATETIME= '2019-12-08';
declare @TimeGrouping INT = 0;
declare @HierarchyGrouping INT = 1;
declare @RecordType INT = 0;
declare @IncludeZeroRecords BIT = 0;
declare @response varchar(max) = '';

declare @results TABLE (
    UserOId BIGINT,
    LocationOId BIGINT,
    ClientUserId varchar(max),
    ClientLocationId varchar(max),
    ClientMarketId varchar(max),
    StraightTime decimal(18,10),
    Overtime decimal(18,10),
    Doubletime decimal(18,10),
    NonCoverageTime decimal(18,10),
    BudgetTime decimal(18,10)
)

declare @formBody varchar(max) = 
'startDate=' + dbo.UrlEncode(convert(varchar, @StartDate, 101)) + 
'&endDate=' + dbo.UrlEncode(convert(varchar, @EndDate, 101)) + 
'&timeGrouping=' + convert(varchar, @TimeGrouping) + 
'&hierarchyGrouping=' + convert(varchar, @HierarchyGrouping) + 
'&recordType=' + convert(varchar, @RecordType) + 
'&includeZeroRecords=' + case when @IncludeZeroRecords = 1 then 'true' ELSE 'false' END;

EXEC dbo.CallApiProc @AccessToken, 'Employment/TimeBreakdown', 'GET', @formBody, @response OUTPUT;

INSERT INTO @results
SELECT 
    JSON_VALUE(value, '$.UserOId'),
    JSON_VALUE(value, '$.LocationOId'),
    JSON_VALUE(value, '$.ClientUserId'),
    JSON_VALUE(value, '$.ClientLocationId'),
    JSON_VALUE(value, '$.ClientMarketId'),
    JSON_VALUE(value, '$.StraightTime'),
    JSON_VALUE(value, '$.Overtime'),
    JSON_VALUE(value, '$.Doubletime'),
    JSON_VALUE(value, '$.NonCoverageTime'),
    JSON_VALUE(value, '$.BudgetTime')
FROM OPENJSON(@response)

SELECT *, u.* FROM @results r
JOIN [User] u on r.UserOId = u.OId
```

Comment: There's no error handling in the COM calls.  See eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086558/set-option-9-in-sql-server-stored-procedure-using-winhttp-winhttprequest-5-1-for/53088460#53088460

Comment: oooooh, thanks for that, I'll definitely add those checks