SQL code check to work with SOAP, problem with getting data
I'm a complete newbie and trying to get data from a SOAP service via SQL query.
I tried it first on reqbin.com, there I get the response, it works ok (see pic).
With SQL I don't get any data. Does anyone has any ideas how to improve the SQL?
    DECLARE @xmlRequest NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <StatusNespolehlivyPlatceRequest xmlns="http://adis.mfcr.cz/rozhraniCRPDPH/">
                <dic>27396819</dic>
            </StatusNespolehlivyPlatceRequest>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>';

DECLARE @response INT;
    DECLARE @responseText NVARCHAR(MAX);

    EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @response OUT;
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @response, 'open', NULL, 'POST', 'https://adisrws.mfcr.cz/dpr/axis2/services/rozhraniCRPDPH.rozhraniCRPDPHSOAP', 'false';
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @response, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8';
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @response, 'send', NULL, @xmlRequest;
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @response, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;

    -- Debugging: Print the raw response
    PRINT @responseText;

reqbin
Many thanks on any advice!!


Which dbms are you using? (The above code isn't really general SQL.)

MS SQL Studio I think ver 19.x

Hello, I would recommend you to use SQL for database queries. And for working with the web service, choose a regular programming language (c#, java, etc.).

Tasks like this are not T-SQL tasks. The OA objects are for compatibility with ancient SQL Server instances (we're talking SQL Server 2000). If you need to work with things like this use middleware to communicate with both the API and the SQL Server instance. What you use is entirely up to you; PowerShell, SSIS, C#, PHP, Python, etc, etc. There are plenty of signicantly better options.

sp_oa-procedures don't support nvarchar(max) as parameters. Try NVARCHAR(4000) for @xmlRequest / @responseText.
Also, feel free to not use sp_oa-procedures altogether, they are discouraged, you should either call web services from outside of SQL Server or use CLR or better suited code to do it.

You can get an nvarchar(max) response with INSERT .. EXEC sp_OAGetProperty .  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086558/set-option-9-in-sql-server-stored-procedure-using-winhttp-winhttprequest-5-1-for/53088460#53088460
